# Proving that every manifold is $T_4$, i.e. every manifold is a normal Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, solution-verification

I'm asking for feedback whether the following proof is valid and sufficient for the claim:

Let $M$ be a manifold. I'm trying to show that every manifold is $T_4$, i.e. if $X, Y \subset M$ are two closed disjoint sets, then there exists neighborhoods $\mathcal{N}_X, \mathcal{N}_Y$ of $X, Y$ in $M$, such that $\mathcal{N}_X \cap \mathcal{N}_Y = \varnothing$. So if $X, Y \subset M$ are two such sets, then let $A = \bigcup_{x\in X}U_x, B = \bigcup_{y \in Y}U_y$ be the unions over the neighborhoods $U_x, U_y$ of every point $x \in X, y \in Y$, which are homeomorphic to the open disk $D^n$ for some $n$. Then $X \subset A, Y \subset B$ and $X \cup Y$ is again homeomorphic $D^n$ with the chart $\varphi$. Since $X, Y \subset A\cup B$ are closed and disjoint, $\varphi\left[X\right], \varphi\left[Y\right] \subset D^n$ are also disjoint and closed. Therefore, there exists some disjoint $\mathcal{N}_X', \mathcal{N}_Y' \subset D^n$ such that $\varphi\left[X\right] \subset \mathcal{N}_X', \varphi\left[Y\right]\subset \mathcal{N}_Y'$. Hence, $\varphi^{-1}\left[\mathcal{N}_X'\right]$ and $\varphi^{-1}\left[\mathcal{N}_Y'\right]$ are disjoint neighborhoods of $X, Y$ in $M$. Thus $M$ is $T_4$.

Comment: A manifold $M$ is a Hausdorff, locally Euclidean and second countable topological space *by definition*. So we are done, aren't we?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I thought so as well, but my intuition involving neighborhoods around closed sets isn't that great, so I decided to be more pedantic. To be precise, we can surely form neighborhoods around $X$ and $Y$ in $M$ by the basis elements, but who is to say (immediately) that these neighborhoods don't necessarily overlap?

Comment: By definition! Otherwise $M$ is not a manifold.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Why? I mean, what is the contradiction of those two neighborhoods do overlap? Does it follow from the charts, like I wrote, or is there something more simple to it?

Comment: Yes, a manifold is $T_4$ by definition. So it must hold. There is nothing to prove (see your title).

Comment: @DietrichBurde My reading material defines an $n$-manifold as a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ such that 1.) $X$ is Hausdorff, 2.) $X$ is second-countable, 3.) every $x \in X$ has a neighborhood $x \in U_x \in \mathcal{T}$ homeomorphic to the open disk $D^n$. This could be the source of confusion, i.e. the $T_4$ property is not an explicit assumption. Hence, do you think that my proof is sufficient to conclude the $T_4$ness?

Comment: How can you conclude that $X\cup Y$ is homeomorphic to $D^n$? What happens if $X\cup Y$ form a disconnected set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof doesn't work. The only proofs I know use the fact that manifolds are paracompact, which follows from second countability. See Theorem 4.81 in my *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* (2nd ed.).

In the interest of helping you learn to think critically about your own proofs, here are some point-by-point comments on what you wrote.

> Let $M$ be a manifold. I'm trying to show that every manifold is
> $T_4$, i.e. if $X, Y \subset M$ are two closed disjoint sets, then
> there exists neighborhoods $\mathcal{N}_X, \mathcal{N}_Y$ of $X, Y$ in
> $M$, such that $\mathcal{N}_X \cap \mathcal{N}_Y = \varnothing$. So if
> $X, Y \subset M$ are two such sets, then let $A = \bigcup_{x\in X}U_x,
> > B = \bigcup_{y \in Y}U_y$ be the unions over the neighborhoods $U_x,
> > U_y$ of every point $x \in X, y \in Y$, which are homeomorphic to the
> open disk $D^n$ for some $n$.

This is not exactly a mistake, but that last sentence is ambiguous. What do you mean by "the neighborhoods"? Every point is going to have infinitely many neighborhoods that are homeomorphic to open balls; do you mean for $A$ and $B$ to be unions of *all* such neighborhoods? Or just a choice of one for each point? Whichever you have in mind, it should be stated explicitly.

> Then $X \subset A, Y \subset B$ and $X\cup Y$ is again homeomorphic $D^n$

Where did this idea come from? $X$ and $Y$ were arbitrary disjoint closed subsets of $M$. You're claiming that their union is homeomorphic to an open ball in $\mathbb R^n$. Do you really believe that's always going to be true?

Maybe you meant to say that $A\cup B$ is homeomorphic to an open ball? But even that is not true. A union of open balls need not be homeomorphic to an open ball, even in $\mathbb R^n$.

> with the chart $\varphi$.

This is more of a stylistic comment: when you say "the chart $\varphi$," it suggests that the symbol $\varphi$ refers to something that has already been defined. It would be better to say "with a chart that we will call $\varphi$," or something like that.

> Since
> $X, A \subset X\cup B$ are closed and disjoint,

Is this a typo? $A$ is not contained in $X\cup B$, it is not closed, and it is not disjoint from $X$. Maybe you meant to say $X,Y\subset A\cup B$?

> $\varphi\left[X\right], \varphi\left[Y\right] \subset D^n$ are also
> disjoint and closed. Therefore, there exists some disjoint
> $\mathcal{N}_X', \mathcal{N}_Y' \subset D^n$ such that
> $\varphi\left[X\right] \subset \mathcal{N}_X',\varphi\left[Y\right]\subset \mathcal{N}_Y'$. Hence,
> $\varphi^{-1}\left[\mathcal{N}_X'\right]$ and
> $\varphi^{-1}\left[\mathcal{N}_Y'\right]$ are disjoint neighborhoods
> of $X, Y$ in $M$. Thus $M$ is $T_4$.

OK, if you previously had shown that $A\cup B$ was homeomorphic to $D^n$, then this last part of the proof would be OK, provided you already know that $\mathbb R^n$ is normal.

In general, when you've written down a proof that you're not sure about, the next step is to read it carefully step by step, asking yourself these questions about every statement in the proof:

- Exactly what does this mean? (I.e., do I know the definitions of all the terms, and have I used them correctly?)
- Exactly why is this true? (Does it follow from a hypothesis? from a previous step? from some other theorem? from some definition?)

Comment: I'm reading your book "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" and i'm loving it. Huge fan here.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback! I was already >90% sure that this proof wouldn't work, but I couldn't find proper discussion about this exact problem, so I decided to post it here. Perhaps next time I should further emphasize parts which I'm not comfortable with. But like they say, you'll learn by making mistakes!

I checked your books, and they look like a fantastic reference for learning about manifolds. Just out of curiosity, based on your teaching experience, how long do you expect it to take to chew through all the three books, assuming that prerequisites are met?

Comment: @SickSeries: At the University of Washington, we teach a four-quarter (12 month) graduate course based on those three books. If you’re very well prepared, and you concentrate on this subject without taking a bunch of other courses, you might be able to shorten that somewhat.